# How do I center the navigation bar text

Tags: xaml, maui

I want to center the navigation bar text without changing the text itself is that it displays (Name of the page)

I tried changing it in the title view but it deletes the existing template and there is no `HorizontalOptions` property I can change in title to be able to center it or move its location.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use [Relative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) to achieve this.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp108.SearchByName"
             Title="TestPage">

     <!-- add Shell.TitleView here -->

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label  Text="{ Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}},Path= Title}"  TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to TestPage!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />               
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi @Burning, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a kind of option for center like you want. I use to use `Shell.SetTitleView` for this and by this I can customise it and add buttons and what ever you want. Exampel on putting it in OnAppearing.

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var stackLayout = new HorizontalStackLayout
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };
    var titel = new Label
    {
        Text = Title,
    };
    stackLayout.Children.Add(titel);
    Shell.SetTitleView(this, stackLayout);
}
```

Alternative is to make a controler with ContentView use it like

```cs
Shell.SetTitleView(this, new PatientTitleView());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to disable the default navigation bar of the content page and design a custom one using Grid of fixed row height. Here is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StackOverflowQnA.Views.NewPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="40,*">
        <Label
            Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
            TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Label 
                Text="Page Content"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Shell, you can set a [custom TitleView](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/customize-the-title-bar-of-a-maui-app-with-these-simple-steps).

Note that it's important to use a *Grid* or *VerticalStackLayout* in order to be able to center something horizontally using the `HorizontalOptions="Center"` setting, because the [official *HorizontalStackLayout* documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/horizontalstacklayout#position-and-size-child-views) states:

> A HorizontalStackLayout only respects the alignment preferences on child views that are in the opposite direction to the orientation of the layout.

And the title can either be bound to using a relative binding or by simply using the `x:Reference` attached property and the page's `x:Name` as a binding source.

So, to fully center your Title label in the *TitleView*, you could do as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SomeProject.SomePage"
             x:Name="MyContentPage"
             Title="MyPage">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding Title, Source={x:Reference MyContentPage}}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <!-- Content goes below this -->

</ContentPage>
```